# Yii Make a model instance that cannot be saved

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

Let's say I have a `Widget` table and the Yii Model class that goes with it.

I want to be able to instantiate it (`$tempWidget = new Widget`) but somehow make sure it cannot be saved to the database. I want to use the model just for the user to test things, simulate...

Obviously, I could just avoid to call `$tempWidget->save()` but I'd like some kind of flag that would prevent save from saving, in case some other part of the code tries to do so.

Comment: Reimplement all the saving methods (`save()`, `insert()`, `update()`, probably others) to check for status of this flag before calling their parent implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish what you want. The easiest way is to modify the models `beforeSave()` method to prevent the model from being able to save by unsetting all the attributes using the `CModel unsetAttributes` method , example:

```
public function beforeSave(){
    $this->attributes = $this->unsetAttributes();
}
```

This will work only if you have rules associated with this model that have required fields (at least one required field), otherwise this would create an entry in your table consisting only of the primary key (assuming PK is auto increment).

Comment: You don't have to unset the attributes. Simply returning false should do the trick. Actually, I believe not calling parent::beforeSave() should be enough.

Comment: Sounds interesting. And how do I trigger this ONLY when I want to? For example something like `new Widget('temp')` ? In the normal cases `new Widget` I want it to save like normal of course.